# Бесконечное подключение io.on('connection')

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express, reactjs

При каждом обновлении страницы на сервере создается +1 io.on('connection').

файл контроллера:

```
module.exports = function(io, client) {
var GameController = {
   gamePage: function(req, res) {
       client.hget('games', 'game.' + req.params.id, function (err, result) {
           if (err) return result(err);
           var game = JSON.parse(result);

           io.on('connection', function (socket) {
               console.log('send');
               console.log(socket.id);
               io.emit('get_bets', game.players);
           });

           res.render('pages/game', {
               title: 'Game - ' + req.params.id,
               user: req.user,
               game: game
           });
       });
   };
return GameController;
});
```

файл роута:

```
module.exports = function(io, client) {
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();
   var GameController = require('controllers/GameController')(io, client); 
   router.get('/:id', GameController.gamePage);
   ...
   return router;
};
```

Клиентская часть на реакте:

```
var Game = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     this.socket = io();

     return {
         bets: null
     }
   },
 socketGetBets: function() {
   var that = this;
   this.socket.on('get_bets', function(data) {
       console.log('get bets');
       that.setState({ bets: data });
   });
   this.socket.on('rand', function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
 },
...
```

Однако после небольшого дебага я выяснил, что проблема точно не в клиентской части

app.js(что касательно сокетов):

```
var socket_io = require('socket.io');

var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;
//route
var game = require('./routes/games')(io, client);
```

bin/www:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io     = app.io;
io.attach( server );
```

Т.е. при обновлении страницы срабатывает on connection и выводит консоль логом слово send. При 2 обновлении страницы уже выводит send send, при третьем - уже 3 и так далее. Потом в итоге я вообще получил warning memory leak. socket.id выводит один и тот же айдишник тоже некое количество раз.